# assign name of global environment variable to all elements of a list

Tags: r, list, names

The title is a bit loose, but I would like to assign to each element of a list the name of that element as it appears in the global environment.

```
a<-1
b<-2
c<-3
l<-list(a,b,c)
```

what I want is the equivalent of the following:

```
l<-list("a"=a,"b"=b,"c"=c)
```

or

```
names(l)<-c("a","b","c")
```

so that `names(l)` return `c("a","b","c")`.
Since I could have lists with lots of elements, I would prefer to avoid all the typing needed for the most straightforward solution (`l<-list("a"=a,"b"=b,"c"=c)`).

I know I can list the names of all variables in the global env with `names(as.list(.GlobalEnv))`, but not all variables in `.GlobalEnv` are contained in the list `l`.
I also know that `deparse(substitute(a))` return `"a"`, but it doesn't work in a loop or a `lapply` call.
Maybe the solution is straightforward, but I cannot figure it out.

How could I do it programmatically?

Comment: `mget(c('a', 'b', 'c'))`??

Comment: the `tibble::lst()` approach is better because saves you from extra typing, but as a fan of `base` R I love this solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`tibble::lst()`](https://tibble.tidyverse.org/reference/lst.html) does this:

```r
library(tibble)

l <- lst(a, b, c)

l
# $a
# [1] 1
# 
# $b
# [1] 2
# 
# $c
# [1] 3
```

Answer (score 1):

If the components are the same length, as in the question, then create a data.frame and convert that to a list.  No packages are needed.

```
a <- 1; b <- 2; c <- 3
data.frame(a, b, c) |> as.list()
```

giving

```
$a
[1] 1

$b
[1] 2

$c
[1] 3
```